# PayPal REST API payment id = IPN txn id

Tags: rest, paypal

Let's assume the PayPal REST API is used to fulfill a standard PayPal payment process. When executing the payment it is returned as 'pending', so the payment is not through, yet. The REST APi provides a payment id:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#execute-an-approved-paypal-payment

When payment is completed the URL of my IPN listener is called, however as said on this site included only a txn_id which seems to be not the same as the payment id of the REST API:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/#id08CKFJ00JYK

So how to match these two ids?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The txn_id of IPN messages are also included with the REST API message but called 'sale id' there.

Comment: When I use the `txn_id` to get the sales details, I get null. Could you please tell me what is the issue?

Answer (score 2):

IPN was designed for supporting the classic APIs on PayPal and the txn_id would have matched the txn_id of a payment made with the classic API.

For payments made via the REST API, you may still be notified via IPN but unfortunately cannot match payments using ids currently. Your best option right now would be to check the attributes of the payment (amount, currency etc) and check that it matches attributes of a payment you were expecting.

Currently this is the existing option for push based notifications. The other option may be to poll at regular intervals and check the status of the payment.

There are certainly limitations to both approaches, and there is webhook support upcoming which would have push based notification support for REST payments to alleviate these issues.

Comment: Its been 2 years that you have posted this answer. Is getting `payment_id` from `IPN`'s `txn_id` still not possible?